# How to revert changes from eas build:configure

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I ran the command `eas update:configure` and now I want to run expo publish but I get this error:
"It seems like your project is configured for EAS Update. Please use 'eas update' instead."

So I'd like to revert my project back to normal so I can use expo publish
N/B: I don't want to use `eas update`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to solve my problem. No command was needed.
You just need to delete `runtimeVersion` and `updates.url` from `app.json` as that is what is added when `eas update:configure`